# Python list comprehension over 2D array

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

If I have a 2D array:

```
 [['Wolfe Lane Community Garden', 'X', 'XXX', 'XX', 
 'XXXXX', 'XX', 'XXX', '0.05', 'XXXX'], ...]
```

I only want to extract the first element and the eighth element.  How can I use list comprehension to do it?  Or a filter function?

I **need** to use list comprehension.

Comment: Why not simply `[l[0], l[6]]`?

Comment: Are those literal X or just placeholders? I think you want to get the elements that aren't completely made of X.

Comment: Correct I realize it should be indices[0, 7] not 6.  Not too sure why everyone is saying 6...

Comment: Counting starts at zero so the seventh element would be at the sixth index.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I know that but it would still be 0, 7. As I want to extract Wolfe... and .05

Comment: If you want the elements with indices 0 and 7 you should edit the question to indicate you want the first and eights elements

Answer (score 4):

You could step:

```
l = [['Wolfe Lane Community Garden', 'X', 'XXX', 'XX',
'XXXXX', 'XX', 'XXX', '0.05', 'XXXX']]

print([sub[::7] for sub in l])
[['Wolfe Lane Community Garden', '0.05']]
```

Use a comp for a list of lists:

```
print([[sub[x]for x in (0,7)] for sub in l ])


[['Wolfe Lane Community Garden', '0.05']]
```

Indexing without a loop:

```
print([[sub[0], sub[7]] for sub in l ])

[['Wolfe Lane Community Garden', '0.05']]
```

Or with a comp and a flat list:

```
print([sub[x] for sub in l for x in (0,7) ])
['Wolfe Lane Community Garden', '0.05']
```

Which you use depends on whether you want a flat list or list of lists.

If you want an efficient way to flatten use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

print(list(chain.from_iterable((sub[0],sub[7]) for sub in l)))
```

Which  you could actually make a list comp:

```
print([ele for ele in chain.from_iterable((sub[0],sub[7]) for sub in l)])
```

Comment: No worries,   was not fully sure what the restrictions were but you should  hopefully get some inspiration from the answers ;)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want the first and eighth element in each sublist of a list of lists. If you have to use list comprehension, you could use `enumerate`:

```
data = [['Wolfe Lane Community Garden', 'X', 'XXX', 'XX', 
         'XXXXX', 'XX', 'XXX', '0.05', 'XXXX'], ...]

indices = [0, 7]

[[x for i, x in enumerate(sublist) if i in indices] for sublist in data]
```

That said one of the other answers, which uses a comprehension to iterate through the indices rather than each sublist in its entirety, is more efficient.

It's worth noting that you can also use `numpy` to do this sort of indexing:

```
import numpy as np
data_arr = np.array(data)
data_arr[:, indices]
```

Comment: Thank you, I realize I didnt have to but I NEED to.

Comment: I need to use LC, however it is a 2D array.

Comment: For a n length array:
[el for index,el in enumerate(list) if (index == 0 or index == len(list) -1) ]

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
myarray = ['Wolfe Lane Community Garden', 'X', 'XXX', 'XX', 
           'XXXXX', 'XX', 'XXX', '0.05', 'XXXX']
first = myarray[0]
seventh = myarray[6]
```

The brackets after the variable name denote the elements of the array being accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you can't just grab the items based on index? This would be the easiest way to do it, specially since you know what items you need to get.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = [['Wolfe Lane Community Garden', 'X', 'XXX', 'XX', 'XXXXX', 'XX', 'XXX', '0.05', 'XXXX']]

print map(itemgetter(0, 7), data)
# OUT: [('Wolfe Lane Community Garden', '0.05')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
lst = [['Wolfe Lane Community Garden', 'X', 'XXX', 'XX', 'XXXXX', 'XX', 'XXX', '0.05', 'XXXX'], ...]
```

Using `map` fucnction:

```
print map(lambda x: [x[0], x[6]], lst)
```

Using `list` comprehensions:

```
print [[x[0], x[6]] for x in lst]
```